# How to make deployable package/folder with grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, web-deployment

when developing programs with Java (and Maven) I get a folder "target" where all files I need (the *.jar and resources of the program) are at one place. That way it's very comfortable to deploy.

Right now I'm deveolping a website. Because I'm using grunt I'd like to know if there is something similar, so I can enter `grunt build` or something like that and grunt copies my minified js/css files, and the resources (html, images, ...) to a target directory.

That way all files I need on the server are at one place, but files that are "unnecessary" for the server (like not minified js files) are not.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very common use case with tools such as Grunt and Gulp; when compiling your JavaScript, LESS / SCSS, CoffeeScript, image compression, and more, you want it to be in one directory.

Commonly with frontend projects, these are compiled to the `dist` or `dest` folders.

However - `grunt` is run entirely by your configuration. If you want to, you could certainly compile all your assets into the `target` directory - do whatever you want. In Grunt, this is commonly configured like the following:

```
js: {
    minify: {
        dest: "target/js"
    }
}
```

Comment: I use that in another project, but for my newest I'm using WebStorm, which automatically minifies my files. So I need something that copies my minified files and resources, that are partially generated by the IDE